Gluten level detector
I was wondering whether it is possible to design gluten level detectors and place them on walls and places.
How, can such a device be designed?
What is the process of designing such a device like?

Gluten detector on a wall? Will someone be smearing food on it? Or is it just a signboard that says yes we have gluten?

@Abel maybe it's for enforcing gluten free food fights

Please [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to achieve. Are you hoping to detect airborne glutenous dust or are you hoping that there is some kind of gluten radar that can detect gluten at a distance and give a quantative measurement. What would your units of measurement be? Have you researched how gluten is detected and measured in laboratory analysis?

From what I can tell by looking at the web, while electronic gluten detectors exist and can be purchased, they look to be snake oil.  If you want to buy one, they will be happy to take your money and when they measure food, they will give the right answer... at least some of the time.  The National Celiac Association says "At this time, there are no reliable at home tests for people with celiac disease." (The record will show that celiac disease is one case where people have to avoid gluten.)
The tests require that you put a sample of the food into the machine with a test strip and wait three minutes.  That is a long way from having something on the wall that detects when there is gluten in the vicinity.  It would be nice to have but as best as I can tell, it does not exist with today's technology.
